# Regex and renaming file error

Tags: python

I was writing a little program that finds all files with given prefix, let's say `'spam'` for this example, in a folder and locates gaps in numbering and renames subsequent folders to fill the gap. Below illustrates a portion of the program that locates the files using a regex and renames it:

```
prefix = 'spam'
newNumber = 005

# Regex for finding files with specified prefix + any numbering + any file extension
prefixRegex = re.compile(r'(%s)((\d)+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)' % prefix)

# Rename file by keeping group 1 (prefix) and group 4 (file extension), 
# but substituting numbering with newNumber
newFileName = prefixRegex.sub(r'\1%s\4' % newNumber, 'spam006.txt')
```

What I was expecting from above was `spam005.txt`, but instead I got `@5.txt`

I figured out I could use `r'%s%s\4' % (prefix, newNumber)` instead and then it does work as intended, but I'd like to understand why this error is happening. Does it have something to do with the `%s` used during `re.compile()`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here:

Your `newNumber` needs to be a string if you want it to be `005` as the first two `0` are dropped when it is being interpreted as an integer.

Your next problem is indeed in your substitution. By using the string formating you effectively create the new regexp `\15\4` (see the `5` in there, that was your `newNumber`). When python sees this it tries to get capturing group `15` and not `group 1` followed by a literal `5`. You can enclose the reference in a `g` like this to get your desired behavior: `\g<1>5\4`

So your code needs to be changed to this:

```
prefix = 'spam'
newNumber = '005'

# Regex for finding files with specified prefix + any numbering + any file extension
prefixRegex = re.compile(r'(%s)((\d)+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+)' % prefix)

# Rename file by keeping group 1 (prefix) and group 4 (file extension), 
# but substituting numbering with newNumber
newFileName = prefixRegex.sub(r'\g<1>%s\4' % newNumber, 'spam006.txt')
```

More information about the `\g<n>` behavior can be found at the end of the [`re.sub` doucmentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)